# Displaying images from outside of java application context.

Tags: java, image

This was a question about testing file upload functionality using a local java server on Windows 7  platform. Since the question evolved with Marko's input, I have edited it, so that those who run into the same challenge do not waste time on evolution details and reach conclusions sooner.

The challenge was to direct uploaded file to a folder outside of the WAR structure and successfully read it from there. For example: upload an image into `c:/tmp/` and then redirect to a confirmation page that displays the image `<img src="c:/tmp/test.jpg" />`. The upload worked but image would not be displayed. And based on Marko's input, this makes sense because browser sitting at localhost will refuse to load anything from local disk structure using `c:`. Maybe these are security considerations similar to those with file input control where we cannot set a default path...

The following tag will work in a locally created .html file but when pasted into a jsp, it won't work. And the difference is that browser uses localhost to get to the jsp.

```
<img src="c:/tmp/test.jpg" />
```

**Solutions**

I think that Marko's answer pretty much defines what needs to be done. While I didn't go with that approach, it clearly is the better way to do it and I will accept that as the answer. Thanks, Marko!

For those who don't want to bother installing a Web server and are willing to live with a bit of a hack, here's what I have done. Again, I didn't want to upload files into my WAR structure because I would then need to remember about clearing that folder before deploying to the server. But that upload folder still needs to be accessible, so I simply created another dummy project and put that upload folder under its WebContent. This works for the purposes of my local testing. The only nuisance is that after uploading a file, I need to refresh the dummy project's WebContent in Eclipse.

```
config.properties

#for uploading files
fileUploadDirectory=C:/javawork/modelsite/tmp/WebContent

#for building html links
publicFileServicePrefix=http://localhost:8080/tmp

<img src="http://localhost:8080/tmp/test.jpg" />  // this works - tmp is the name of my dummy project.
```

Comment: `<img src="file://c:/tmp/2012/04/viewicons.gif" />`  Once deployed, and loaded by a browser **here,** that would point to a (fictitious) location on the local file system of **this** PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are citing literally the HTML that goes to the browser (the one that you access via "vieew source") then this has nothing to do with Java. The browser is the one who interprets these links. If they fail to load, the problem is in the browser/file system.

**UPDATE**

According to the results of your additional diagnostics, I conclude that the browser (sensibly!) refuses to load anything from your local disk if it is referenced from an HTML file coming from an internet URL, even when that URL is `localhost`.

**UPDATE 2**

(Deleted, irrelevant)

**UPDATE 3**

However you handle the files uploaded to the server, it's definitely not going to look like your solution -- the file is on the server's local filesystem, not client's. This sort of thing can be handled at the Apache HTTP server level -- reserve an URL section for static content and configure Apache with a base directory from which to serve the static content. Even if you run the server locally, on the same machine where you test it, you still need to  go through the network interface.

Comment: I'm citing using my test html file which works fine. I paste those two lines into my jsp and no luck. The page source does contain those two lines, they are identical to what I cited and no images display. Chrome displays nothing, IE displays an icon for "broken image". I understand this does not imply Java issue but it may have something to do with context. Here's my url `http://localhost:8080/SiteAdmin/file?fileId=1`

Comment: So if you save the HTML you received from the server to a regular HTML file on the disk and open that file in the browser, then everything works?

Comment: Tried it. As the part of the save, the browser creates a files directory and downloads the image into it, together with js and css files. The htm is a bit manipulated but that's expected, I guess. The image path is set to the local copy of it. When I open the htm file, still no image displays.

Comment: No, you have to save the exact same HTML. If necessary, use copy-paste from View Source.

Comment: Marko, try to save a page with images on it. You'll see that the htm file will have image references changed to local copies.

Comment: So I put a manually created html file in the same directory where my page was saved. I put `<html><img src="c:/tmp/2012/04/viewicons.gif" /></html>` in it and this test file works. Now, I edit the htm file saved, remove everything and paste `<html><img src="c:/tmp/2012/04/viewicons.gif" /></html>` and it won't display the image.

Comment: Looks like I'm running into security issues... See updated post.

Comment: Marko, I guess what you have provided in your update makes sense. But then, how do you handle file uploads in a locally tested java application? These uploads just cannot go into WAR. They must be kept outside.

Comment: Upload is a completely different thing -- it's a POST request where the body comes from the content of a file. It is not referenced from the HTML page and it is not interpreted by the browser (like the image  file gets interpreted into an image). That operation is totally safe.

Comment: Hmm, I see I didn't answer with my previous comment. However you handle the files uploaded to the server, it's definitely not going to look like your solution -- the file is on the server's local filesystem, not client's. This sort of thing can be handled at the Apache HTTP server level -- reserve an URL section for static content and configure Apache with a base directory from which to serve the static content.

Comment: Well, yes... But to test an upload of an image, you want to see that image displayed in the browser. There must be a way to do this locally. I can't imagine java developers having to deploy to the server in order to test such functionality.

Comment: Ah, that's what you're talking about! For that you're going to need Javascript, it's not going to be simple <img src>

Comment: Not a preview, Marko. Upload an image and redirect to a page that displays the image (together with some other things). And all this with an image sitting outside of application context.

Comment: If you test locally, then you must have an Apache HttpServer locally installed and configured. That's the way I do it and that's pretty much the norm.